# "Cat" a random file in terminal

Tags: command-line, bash

I would like to create a bash script that allows me to display a file using "cat".
The thing is that displaying a simple file is easy even for me, but I would like to randomly display a file in a folder in my terminal so that every time I open one, there is a random file displayed.

Could someone help me?

edit: those files are just images made of ASCII characters, their size is about 2-3ko

Comment: What happens if this "random" file is 20 GB large?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414164/how-can-i-select-random-files-from-a-directory-in-bash.

Answer (score 5):

It's your funeral. . . I take no responsibility for what this will do to your terminal (you need to make sure there are no binary files in the directory) nor how much crap will be shown in it. If you really want to do this, you can use (with thanks to @DavidFoerster and @muru for improvements):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
targetDir="/home/terdon/foo"
## Save the files in the array $files
files=( "$targetDir"/* )
## Cat a random file
cat "${files[RANDOM % ${#files[@]}]}"
```

Comment: You could use 'diff' to determine if the file is text or binary and also add a size check.

Comment: Why not `cat "${files[$(($RANDOM % ${#files[@]}))]}"` (assuming `files` isn't empty)?

Comment: @DavidFoerster actually, in `[]`, you're already in an arithmetic context, so it can be further condensed to: `${files[RANDOM % ${#files[@]}]}`

Comment: How would I assign `"${files[RANDOM % ${#files[@]}]}"` to a variable while taking into account directories/files with spaces? Tried for half an hour but nothing seems to work.

Comment: @HashimAziz assigning is fine, for one thing `${files[RANDOM % ${#files[@]}]}` is already a variable and for another `foo=${files[RANDOM % ${#files[@]}]}` works perfectly well. Your problem most likely that you are then trying to `cat` the variable without quoting it. `cat ${files[RANDOM % ${#files[@]}]}`or `cat $foo` won't work if your file names have spaces, but `cat "${files[RANDOM % ${#files[@]}]}" or cat "$foo"` will. If you need more help, please post a new question with some example files and explain what you need to do.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with terdon that it's your funeral, but let it not be said that we prevented you from screwing yourself over in multiple ways:

```
find /some/path -type f -print0 | shuf -zn1 | xargs -0 cat
```

What does it do?

- `find`'s `-print0`, `shuf`'s `-z` and `xargs`'s `-0` all combine to deal with NUL-delimited input. That and `/` are the only characters not allowed in filenames, so it's the safest for passing around filenames and paths.
- `find` will output a list of all the files (recursively) in `/some/path`.
- `shuf` will shuffle the input lines and output exactly one line (`-n1`).
- `xargs cat` will then use that one line as an argument to `cat`.

Comment: I don't understand the comments about safety, how can this possiblly be destructive in the OP's use case where the contents of the directory is known? I personally need it to randomly `cat` a text file from a directory of them.